# Publishing a GSheet to the web

Tags: iframe, google-sheets, publish

I created a simple spreadsheet with inputs and outputs and I want to share it with the world on a blog. I would like each visitor to have the opportunity to enter their own inputs and see the output real time.

Is this possible without them having to download a copy of my spreadsheet to their local drive?

Best,

D

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is simple, there is a built-in option in Google Sheets to publish or *embed* the spreadsheet. If you choose embed you will Google will give you HTML code that you can *embed* in your blog.

### The steps are as follows:

1. Open a file in Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides.
2. At the top, click File and then Publish to the web.
3. In the window that appears, click Embed.
4. Choose a publishing option:

   - Spreadsheet: Choose to publish the entire spreadsheet or individual sheets.
   - Presentation: Choose a presentation size and how quickly to change the slides.
5. Click Publish.
6. Copy the HTML in the text box and paste it into your site or blog.

---

### Reference:

- [Embed files](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

---

### Suggested reading:

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)
- [GAS Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [Deploying GAS as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)